# Structure private field accessibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio, structure

I noticed that intellisense let me "see" private field of other structure "instances".
I does not understand why i can bypass getter, i think this is dangerous (i'm using VS2019).

[image]

Comment: Your class is trusted to know how to safely access the fields that it itself defines. Access modifiers are about what *other* types can interact with it's members. And it is about *types*, not *instances*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the clarification, but is this a new feature? I does not remeber to ever seen this behaviour before.
I would also ask if directly access the field (when allowed) instead of calling the getter, can give some performance boost.

Comment: It's a common feature of access modifiers across multiple languages. It's been this way in C# since 1.0. I can't think of any language with access modifiers based on instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private fields can be accessed from *code* in the *same class or struct*, regardless of *instance*. This is not something new and the way the [private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) access modifier is supposed to work and always have worked in C#.